# set height of child div in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am new to angularJS and trying to find height of child div from parent div.I want to do it without jquery. I tried lot of solution from here but non of them working for me.

I have one more doubt, in jquery we can use $(".class").height() and $(".class").css("value"), like this angularJS provides any option to set the properties to parent and child div.

here i am using directive concept to set these things,

Code

```
myApp.directive('orientable', function () {       
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

          //this both will work fine
           alert(element.children()[0].offsetHeight);
           alert(element.children()[1].offsetHeight);

           debugger;

           element.children()[0].height();
          //Uncaught TypeError: element.children(...)[0].height is not a function(…) 

           //this bellow code is showing the error
           element.children()[0].css('height','250px');
       //Uncaught TypeError: element.children(...)[0].css is not a function(…) 


    }
}
});

 <div orientable class=main ng-app="myApp">
    <div class=ele1> </div>
     <div class=ele2> </div>
      <div class=ele3> </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddile](http://jsfiddle.net/renjithgovind/xkz4xdf1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not Angular guy but try this

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('orientable', function () {       
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

               alert(element.children()[0].offsetHeight);
               alert(element.children()[1].offsetHeight);

               element.children()[0].clientHeight;
               element.children()[0].style.height="250px";


        }
    }
});
```

`css()` and `height()` are stuff from jQuery.

For height() you could use clientHeight - it would include and padding, for css you could go with style.height.

Answer (score 1):

With `element.children()[0].height();` you are using jquery, because [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) is a typical jquery function.

Replace it with `element.children()[0].clientHeight` and you should be good to go. Remember that javascript provides various functions to get a element height:

`clientHeight` includes the height and the vertical padding of your element.

`offsetHeight` includes the height, the vertical padding and vertical borders of your element.

Comment: which one(clientHeight  or offsetHeight ) is equal to .height() of jquery

Answer (score 1):

When you access an element like `element.children()[0]` you access the raw DOM element which doesn't have css/height methods as those come from jquery.

You could set the height this way instead `element.children()[0].style.height = "200px"`